# A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-hosting

I have just deployed my asp.net mvc-2 website to a server (using dotnetpanel). But getting this error

```
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

What settings I needs? Its dotnetpanel based hosting server.

Comment: Adding index.html file solved my problem

Comment: What to do if the issue occurred at development time. While running the application from Visual studio. **How to resolve this?**  I am running ASP.NET MVC application

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Which version of IIS is your host running?  One thing to try is to put a dummy default.aspx file in the root folder (this will not be used when MVC is working, but can get rid of this problem).

Comment: Adding default.aspx Page Solved my Problem

Comment: Why would you have .aspx files in a MVC application? You would use Views not WebForms files. This is not the answer, it is a hack.

Comment: @RobKing I never said it wasn't a hack, but parts of asp.net MVC itself rely on hacks.

Comment: Alternatively you could fix the problem by adding <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> to the config file.

Answer (score 38):

The answer marked will help you eliminate the error but it will not get MVC working. The answer to the problem is to add this line to the web.config file in system.webServer:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: This fixed my MVC 5 WebAPI2 site on IIS 7.5 with .net 4.5 installed on the server (not 4.5.1)

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem on SBS with IIS7 for ASP.Net MVC 5.

Comment: This really should be the accepted the answer. After publishing an MVC4 to azure, I was getting _You do not have permission to view this directory or page_ error. I was stuck for 3 days but this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Here's NancyFx's docs on the web.config settings https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-asp.net  There are a few updates that'll get this working.

Comment: How about ASP.NET Core 3+

Comment: you won’t have this problem with .net core

Comment: @RobKing I'm actually having this problem with .net core. Any ideas?

Comment: i'm also having the same problem with dotnetcore3.1

Answer (score 21):

Following applies to IIS 7

The error is trying to tell you that one of two things is not working properly:

- There is no default page (e.g., index.html, default.aspx) for your
  site.  This could mean that the Default Document "feature" is
  entirely disabled, or just misconfigured.
- Directory browsing isn't enabled.  That is, if you're not serving a default page for your
  site, maybe you intend to let users navigate the directory contents
  of your site via http (like a remote "windows explorer").

See the following link for instructions on how to diagnose and fix the above issues.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942062/en-us

If neither of these issues is the problem, another thing to check is to make sure that the application pool configured for your website (under IIS Manager, select your website, and click "Basic Settings" on the far right) is configured with the same .Net framework version (in IIS Manager, under "Application Pools") as the targetFramework configured in your web.config, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
```

I'm not sure why this would generate such a seemingly unrelated error message, but it did for me.

Comment: Ensuring the .NET versions matched fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same error posted by OP while trying to debug an ASP.NET website using IIS Express server. IIS Express is a light-weight web server used by Visual Studio to run the website when we press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug website code.

How to fix it?

Open project solution in Visual Studio (VS) **>** Expand solution explorer **>** Expand the web application project node (**StudentInfo** in my case) **>** Right click on the web page which has to be loaded when website starts (**StudentPortal.aspx** in my case) **>** Select **Set as Start Page** option from the context menu as shown below.

[image]

**Root cause**: I concluded that the start page which is the default document for the website wasn't set correctly or had got messed up somehow during development.

Comment: This was the best solution for me, mine wasn't set correctly

Comment: Hii..I'm doing the same thing that my dotnet core application  i'm running on  iis. i also  set the startup  project .. but not solving my issue ..please do  give any other suggestion  as i  already wasted loads of time on  it ..i'm using dotnet core 3.1 ..

Answer (score 2):

Have you add a default route to this class?

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes (RouteCollection routes) {`
        //"HomePage" is the root view of your app
        routes.MapRoute (
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {
                controller = "Home", action = "HomePage", id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
}
```

`
After that in Global.asax.cs add this line to Application_Start() method:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes);
```

I had this problem after I made an upgrade from MVC4 to MVC5 following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) post and I had that line commented for a reason that I've forgot.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur if you do something stupid (like I did) and place the api url in the "Project Url" (e.g. http://localhost:59088/api/Product) on the Project Properties->Web tab instead of specifying it in the "Specific Page" text box. This causes Visual Studio to go ahead and create an APP called ProjectName/api/Product, and this will expect a default page. The only way to undo this is to go to C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express and use appcmd.exe to delete it like so

```
>.\appcmd.exe delete APP "ProjectName/api/Product"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late to post answer, but I found completely differently scenario. I tried all possible solution given above but that not works for me.
I found very silly mistake / ignorance in my case
**I checked IIS manager window carefully and found ASP.NET section was missing there.**
I have made Turn Windows features on for ASP.NET, below is the steps

> 1. Open Control Panel
> 2. Programs\Turn Windows Features on or off Internet
> 3. Information Services World Wide Web Services Application development
> 4. Check for - >Features ASP.Net

I have closed IIS manager window and reopened it, now ASP.NET section is visible.
[image]

Just browse hosted website and it's up on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your default page named as **index.aspx** and not something like **main.aspx** or **home.aspx** .
 And also see to it that **all your properties in your class matches exactly with that of your table in the database**. Remove any properties that is not in sync with the database. That solved my problem!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The culprit might lie in the fact that Global.asax has been placed in the wrong directory inside the mvc project. In my case it was placed under /Views but I had to move it should have been placed under the root folder of the project.

In your case you might be the exact opposite - run some tests and see for yourself.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41467885/863651

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to install the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package.

I was getting the same message as you did, but then noticed I couldn't even hit a breakpoint in `Startup.cs` which then let me to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20204884/413785).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in a WebForms application, the error clearly says that `A default document is not configured` and it was true in my case, the default document was not configured. What worked for me is that I clicked on my site and on the middle pane in iis there is an option named `Default Document`. In the `Default Document` you have to check if the default page of the application exists or not.

The default page of my application was index.aspx and it wasnt present on iis `Default Document` window. So I made a new entry of index.aspx and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS Setting in your plesk panel and enter default document name first page of website (deafault values are

```
 Index.html
Index.htm
Index.cfm
Index.shtml
Index.shtm
Index.stm
Index.php
Index.php3
Index.asp
Index.aspx
Default.htm
Default.asp
Default.aspx)
```

This will work properly