# "This type of page is not served." for classic ASP subdirectory

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am trying to run one of my classic asp projects and it is throwing the error *This type of page is not served*.

This error is occurring when I browse one particular subdirectory alone. The remaining ASP pages are working fine in the same project.

The project is running on IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Enterprise and VS 2013 Professional.

**Complete error description:**

> The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Update:**

I didn't find any separate app pool or virtual direcoty for issue subdirectory. But interestingly when i turned off IIS and try to browse the issue directory page still it is displaying the error where as for home page it is thorowing "**Not Found**[Http error 404.]". Requests to subdirectory are not pointing to my local IIS? Is there any chance causing this because of IIS express which installed along with VS?

[image]

Comment: Possibly covered here?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247982/c-sharp-and-razor-the-type-of-page-you-have-requested-is-not-served-because-it

Comment: Is it actually a classic asp page which is throwing this error - ie does it have the file extension ".asp"

Comment: One more thought - are you trying to view the page via IIS or are you using the built in server which comes with Visual Studio and which VS will use by default as a development server?  IIS supports Classic ASP while the VS server doesn't

Comment: Your question is not detailed enough to warrant a complete answer.  Have you checked that classic asp is working anywhere on the site?  Have you enbaled classic asp (must be installed and enabled per site on iis 7 +).

Comment: @Frank remaing asp pages are working fine within this project, problem with only one subdirectory. if i copy & rename that SD, while browsing those pages are working fine. Probably any access restrictions in IIS for that sd? I am not understanding :(.

Comment: @John I could access the home page of the project from IIS Browse option and directly from the browser as well. The error is firing when i am trying to access the pages from that particualr subdirectory.

Comment: It sounds as if the subdirectory might have a separate app pool, which is theoretically possible to set up but rather a strange thing to do

Comment: @John is probably right on.  The sub drirectory can be part of a different iss application pool, a virtual directory, or other.   As a test can you create test.asp in the directory with just a basic response write?  It might sound dumb, but i have seen it where you have files like default.asp.txt which will not server anything.  Also, make sure you dont have a specific web.config there which is re configruing handler mappings, or in your root web.config you dont have anything weird going on with that directory.   Lastly, try copying the folder and seeing if the 2nd directory has the issue.

Comment: Forgot to say, may want to look at rewrite rules as well.

Comment: @John and Frank Thanks for your reponse, please check the updated question once.

Comment: Without access to your server, any suggestions we make are just educated guesses, do you have any tech support people who can help you?  One thing which is strange about your second screencap is that it is an asp.net error page.  IIS would not normally try to serve a Classic ASP page through the .net framework.

Comment: I dont think you could get IIS-Express and IIS to run on the same port (80).

Comment: @Frank you are right, just i was wondering about possible causes of the error[since they are throwing even when IIS turned off]