# Using Razor with just ASP.NET Hosted on IIS (Not MVC)

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor

I'm trying to use Razor without MVC.. I've created a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application and then installed the following package: `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor`

I've then got an `Index.cshtml` in the root of my directory but when I launch the site I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, 
    and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

If I add an `Index.html` file it works fine, but I'd like to use Razor. Is there any additional configuration I need to do? My `web.config` looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>

  <runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and IIS Express 8

### Note

All I've done is create a new empty web application, left Web API, Web Forms, MVC unchecked, no authentication.

Installed: `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor` through nuget.

Created `Index.cshtml` page in the root and launched the site locally to reproduce the error.

Comment: State your purpose? Is it for a complete web page generation or to use something like a template to generate documents (like html documents)?

Comment: To generate complete web pages.. More specifically I want to make use of the bundling in `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`

Comment: Well, if you want to hear it from the horses mouth: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5266583/145682

Comment: But the answers there will definitely help you I guess...

Comment: Not really because they're talking about using Razor syntax (@) inside an .aspx page, where as I just want IIS to render a .cshtml page rendered as html?

Comment: That feature is called *[Asp.net Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2)*, and you need WebMatrix installed for it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie `Razor` _syntax_ doesn't "require" controllers - exactly as BillBaffBoff stated...

Comment: I don't know why anyone feels adding a single controller is not a good idea in this instance (why fight city hall), but I have removed my answer. Good luck.

Comment: I see your point but adding in the whole MVC framework just to get razor working seems a bit verbose..

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   A default document is not configured for the requested URL, 
>       and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

The above is more indicative of an IIS/ASP.Net matter than "Razor" *sytnax*. Does the site you configured have ASP.Net (enabled?), AppPool (.net 4), etc? The reason *index.html* works is that it's just-an-html-page that IIS will happily serve vs. a `csthtml` (or `aspx`, `vbhtml`) which are *application specific* (ASP.Net).

- [Razor **syntax**](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) doesn't "require" MVC - you can use it happily and effectively for any model you want - applications (MVC included) or "web sites" (WebMatrix, WebPages, etc).
- I have never tried Razor on WebForms (aspx) pages, nor do I think I want to try :) but if you do (or really need to), here's [Scott Hanselman on mixing WebForms and Razor in your ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)

Comment: I'm not using Razor in WebForms or MVC, at the moment its just an empty ASP site with 1 file (Index.cshtml) when I run it in IIS Express using Visual Studio 13 I get that error

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff - you mean "use IIS Express" in VS or some other way (e.g. like manually creating an IIS site)? What happens if you explicitly browse `index.chtml`?

Comment: Yeah, IIS Express in VS. When I browse `/Index.cshtml` it says the server isn't allowed to display that file type. I've got colleagues to try this on their machine and they all get the same error.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff That's a sign that your "site" isn't setup to handle cshtml files (IIS/ASP.net settings and/or needed assemblies). Does your `/bin` folder have the [necessary dlls to handle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5908903/304683)?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27660108/3506427). Your problem can be related to the mapping of your resorces.